# i have one encrypted txt file and the below encryption code. how to decrypt it?

Tags: encryption

public string Encrypt(string plainText) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

```
        foreach (char c in plainText) {
            if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                int num = (int)c;
                num = ((num + 10) * 2) + 2;

                sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", num.ToString());
            }
            else if (c == ' ') {
                sb.Append("| ");
            }
            else if (c == '\n') {
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

The encryption code uses the formula `num = ((num + 10) * 2) + 2;`

Reversing that is `num = ((num - 2) / 2) - 10;`

Now convert it back from an integer to a character.

You will need to recognise spaces and newlines in the cyphertext separately.